# FBX Importer - Vertex Color

Tags: opengl, c++, fbx

I imported vertex positions, indices and normals successfully in OpenGL using fbx sdk, but I just can't figure out how to import vertex colors. I tried to fetch the pointer to array of colors trough mesh layer but it returns null. Can anyone help me with this one please?

Answer (score 1):

they are stored in normalized *GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE​s*, a single color is 4 bytes, and are held under the KFbxLayer class and KFbxLayerElement class is the base class for Layer Elements and describes how all is arranged in memory.
example layers

```
KFbxLayerElementVertexColor KFbxLayerElementNormal KFbxLayerElementUV KFbxLayerElementTexture KFbxLayerElementMaterial KFbxLayerElementPolygonGroup
```

Create an instance of KFbxMesh object and a new KFbxNode object containing that mesh. Then access KFbxNodeAttribute or the KFbxLayerContainer also holds layers, maybe your vertex colors are in there

refer to the sdk documentation [Autodesk](http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/index.html?url=WS8e4c2438b09b7f9c-50e6e6531197ccd93c5-7ffa.htm,topicNumber=d0e2241)